# Group by within Sub Query

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, subquery

Hi I have the code below which brings through a total by due and complete as well as the date. However I want to summarize by date, please can someone assist?

```
        SELECT  CONVERT(varchar(15), GRLastDt, 111) as Date_,      
                (
                    SELECT        COUNT(*) AS Expr1
                    FROM            dbo.AN_Admin_VendorReturns_090_Final
                    WHERE        (Complete = 'X') AND (CONVERT(varchar(15), GRLastDt, 111) >= GETDATE() - 60)
                ) AS Complete,
                (
                    SELECT        COUNT(*) AS Expr1
                    FROM            dbo.AN_Admin_VendorReturns_090_Final AS AN_Admin_VendorReturns_090_Final_1
                    WHERE        (Complete <> 'X') AND (CONVERT(varchar(15), GRLastDt, 111) >= GETDATE() - 60)
                )  AS DUE

                    FROM            dbo.AN_Admin_VendorReturns_090_Final
        group by CONVERT(varchar(15), GRLastDt, 111)
```

Comment: What is the reason for converting the date to varchar in `<=` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  CGRLastDt as Date_,    
SUM(CASE WHEN Complete = 'X' Then 1 Else 0 END)   AS Complete,
SUM(CASE WHEN Complete <> 'X' Then 1 Else 0 END)   AS Due
FROM dbo.AN_Admin_VendorReturns_090_Final
WHERE GRLastDt >= GETDATE() - 60
GROUP BY GRLastDt
```

Please note that I haven't validated this SQL for syntax and doing this in notepad.